# Passing list of defined values as parameter C#

Tags: c#

How can I make my method have defined list of values that can be passed. I've seen this in VB.net, but can't find it in C#, and it dosen't look like `enum`.

```
class Test
{
    List { active, all, completed}

    public string get(string a, List b)
    {
       // some code
    }

    string a = get("foo", active);
    string b = get("foo", all);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a enum to me.

Comment: Pass a custom class with the properties instead...?

Comment: Can you be more specific why you can not use enum?

Comment: Downvoted, you don't explain why `test.active` isn't valid.  When using an `enum`, that is how it was designed to be used in c#, I would even wager that 99.99% of c# programmers use it that way.  If you alter that way, other programmers won't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If enum is called test, I need to pass test.active and I don't want that. I need to pass only active

What you can do is use the `using static` keyword when you want to use the enum, then you can just use the word you want.

```
namespace Foo
{
    class Test
    {
        public string get(string a, List b)
        {
           // some code
        }
    }

    public enum List { active, all, completed}
}
```

used like

```
using Foo;
using static Foo.List;

public void Example()
{
    var test = new Test(); 
    //Because of "using static Foo.List;" you don't need to use "List.active"
    string a = test.get("foo", active);
    string b = test.get("foo", all);
}
```

Comment: Never seen use of enum in that way. +1. But still I would prefer explicit way of passing enum.